# Unable to navigate from one stack screen to a screen of completely different stack?

Tags: javascript, react-native

So in my AppNavigator.js I have two Stack.Navigators

```
function LoginStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Shop" component={Shop} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Inside the login component, when user is successfully logged in, I am trying navigate to the HomeStack using the below code.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function Login() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

    handleLogin = () => {
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
    }
    
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    }

    return(
        // Some view that triggers handleLogin 
    )

}
```

Here I am getting the error

The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'Home'?

Meanwhile I am successfully able to navigate to the screen in the same stack using the below code

```
navigation.navigate('Register')
```

How can I solve this issue? thanks in advance.